# r: Fill two dataframe columns with the t-statistic and p-value from t.test

Tags: r

Given the American Community Survey dataset from [Lock5Data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Lock5Data/index.html), I want to calculate the t-stat (and its Bonferroni-corrected p-value) of incomes for each combination of races.  I'd like to store the results in a dataframe with columns 'race1', 'race2, 'tstat', and 'pval'.  This way I can sort the dataframe to show the biggest (or most significant) differences in income.

```
library(Lock5Data)
data("ACS")
ACS$Sex <- factor(ACS$Sex, labels = c("Female","Male"))
sub_acs <- subset(ACS, select = c("Income","Sex","Race"))
sub_acs <- na.omit(sub_acs)

# form results df (t_df)
race_unique <- unique(sub_acs$Race)
t_df <- expand.grid(race1 = race_unique, race2 = race_unique)
t_df <- t_df[t_df$race1 != t_df$race2,]
rownames(t_df) <- NULL

# fill df col with t-stat
t_df$tstat <- t.test(sub_acs[sub_acs$Race == t_df$race1,]$Income, 
           sub_acs[sub_acs$Race == t_df$race2,]$Income, 
           p.adjust.methods='bonferroni')$statistic

# fill df col with p_val
t_df$pval <- t.test(sub_acs[sub_acs$Race == t_df$race1,]$Income, 
           sub_acs[sub_acs$Race == t_df$race2,]$Income, 
           p.adjust.methods='bonferroni')$p.value
```

Unfortunately, the results df `t_df` appears to only show the first result for each test repeated down all the rows.  How do I correctly map the t-statistic and p-value results?  Answers that make my current solution more elegant and portable are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider `Map` (the simplified wrapper to `mapply`) and use *t_df* as only a helper dataframe to pass unique values into the **m**ultiple **apply** method.

```
t_df <- subset(expand.grid(race1 = race_unique, race2 = race_unique), race1 < race2)

ttest_proc <- function(r1, r2) {    
   output <- t.test(sub_acs[sub_acs$Race == r1,]$Income, 
                    sub_acs[sub_acs$Race == r2,]$Income, 
                    p.adjust.methods='bonferroni')

   df <- data.frame(race1 = r1,
                    race2 = r2, 
                    t_stat = output$statistic, 
                    p_val = output$p.value)    
   return(df)    
}

df_list <- Map(ttest_proc, t_df$race1, t_df$race2)

final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```

Comment: When running your code I had a problem. Shouldn't you use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in the call to `expand.grid`?

Comment: Sure but it depends too on actual data types from *acs* dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
cbn <- t(combn(as.character(race_unique), 2))
pval <- numeric(nrow(cbn))
tstat <- numeric(nrow(cbn))

for(i in seq_len(nrow(cbn))){
    a <- subset(sub_acs, Race %in% cbn[i, ])
    tt <- t.test(Income ~ Race, data = a, p.adjust.methods = 'bonferroni')
    pval[i] <- tt$p.value
    tstat[i] <- tt$statistic
}

result <- data.frame(race1 = cbn[, 1], race2 = cbn[, 2], p.value = pval, statistic = tstat)
result 
#  race1 race2     p.value  statistic
#1 white black 0.190337465 -1.3173942
#2 white other 0.007776557 -2.7231317
#3 white asian 0.203332407  1.2831045
#4 black other 0.365064209  0.9092968
#5 black asian 0.050391428  1.9782605
#6 other asian 0.005943459  2.8158303
```

Comment: This does what I want and answers the question, but what did I do wrong in my vectorized approach?  I don't mind an iterative approach since the dataframe is so small, but I would like some performance at scale.

Comment: Currently, you are only assigning *tstat* and *pval* columns **once** and not iteratively through all combinations of *race1* and *race2*. T-test cannot be vectorized in one call as you expect a different result with each pass.